# Options for including and excluding conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am working in Wordpress and trying to build a query with where I need to include and exclude conditions.  I am not excluding the delete condition correctly (See results and expected results). I want to exclude from my query all records where '_fep_delete_by_1' exists. I am looking for other options for excluding records where '_fep_delete_by_1' exists.

My Tables

```
wp_posts
 ID | post_author | post_parent | post_type    | post_title | post_date
2258  163           0             fep_message    a
2262  1             2258          fep_message    re:a
2264  163           2258          fep_message    re:a
1698  1             0             fep_message    b
1692  1             0             fep_message    c

wp_postmeta
meta_id | post_id | meta_key          | meta_value
14696     2258      _fep_participants   1
14697     2258      _fep_participants   163
9819      1698      _fep_participants   163
9820      1698      _fep_participants   1
9759      1692      _fep_participants   163
9760      1692      _fep_participants   1
9815      1692      _fep_delete_by_1    1499496054
13751     1698      _fep_delete_by_163  1501044119

wp_user
ID   | user_login 
1      myname
163    theirname
```

My Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p.post_date, p.post_title, uf.user_login AS from_login, ut.user_login AS to_login 
FROM wp_posts AS p
    JOIN wp_postmeta pm_to
    ON 
        ((p.post_parent = pm_to.post_id 
        AND p.post_parent <> 0) 
        OR
        (p.id = pm_to.post_id
        AND p.post_parent = 0)) 
    AND pm_to.meta_key = '_fep_participants' 
    AND pm_to.meta_value <> p.post_author 
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm_delete
    ON 
        ((pm_delete.post_id = p.post_parent AND pm_delete.meta_value = '_fep_delete_by_1')
        OR
        (pm_delete.post_id = p.id AND pm_delete.meta_value = '_fep_delete_by_1'))
LEFT JOIN wp_users AS uf ON uf.ID = p.post_author 
LEFT JOIN wp_users AS ut ON ut.ID = pm_to.meta_value
WHERE (p.post_type = 'fep_message' AND uf.user_login = 'myname'
OR p.post_type = 'fep_message' AND ut.user_login = 'myname')
AND pm_delete.post_id IS NULL
AND p.post_date >= '2017-07-07 00:00:00'  
AND p.post_date <= '2017-08-12 23:59:59'
ORDER BY p.post_date
```

The result it produces is:

```
id     |post_date              |post_title     |from_login     |to_login    
1692    2017-07-07 11:45:03     c               myname          theirname   
1698    2017-07-08 16:28:18     b               myname          theirname   
2258    2017-08-11 23:15:10     a               theirname       myname  
2262    2017-08-12 16:48:05     re:a            myname          theirname
```

The result that was expected is:

```
id     |post_date              |post_title     |from_login     |to_login    
1698    2017-07-08 16:28:18     b               myname          theirname   
2258    2017-08-11 23:15:10     a               theirname       myname  
2262    2017-08-12 16:48:05     re:a            myname          theirname
```

What may I be doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't understand why you expect any dates at all in the result

Comment: I neglected to put the dates in my table.  Sorry about that.  The issue is with the _fep_delete_by_1.  How do I exclude that?

Comment: Can the expected result be different because of the or statement in the where ? Since the value 1692 is only in the wp_posts and not in the wp_postmeta

Comment: The column that contains the value `_fep_delete_by_1` is `meta_key`, not `meta_value` as you used in your query. For debugging, it helps to do a `select *` to see everything you get.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Solarflare, one more time helping me out on my project.  That was it, meta_key.  Nice to have other eyes look at my work.  All works as it should now.